# Granting read/execute permission for 'other users' in a directory tree

Tags: chmod

There is the following directory tree in several of my Linux boxes:

`/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target`

Each of the dir[1-4] directories have several directories under them and all these directories (and its sub-directories) have `750` permissions. Now, I want to `others` to browse through the 'target' directory and its sub-directories. Running `chmod -R o+rx` on `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target`, does change the permission on `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target` to `755`, but the `others` users cannot go to that directory since there is no `r-x` permission on its parent directories. On one of the servers, I worked around this by granting the following:

```
chmod -R o+x /dir1
chmod -R o+rx /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target
```

Considering that the above command would give 'traverse' permission on all the subdirectories of /dir[1-4] too, is there a better command to provide traversal permissions on only /dir[1-4] directories and r-x permission on the 'target' directory?

Comment: You've just given everyone the permission to execute every _file_ in the `/dir1` directory (and below) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `x` permissions for "others" on `/dir1/dir2/.../target` and all intermediate directories (except for the root directory), and `r` permissions on the `target` directory at the end of the path:

```
dir=/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target

chmod o+r "$dir"
while [ -n "$dir" ]; do
    chmod o+x "$dir"
    dir=${dir%/*}
done
```

For the given directory path, this would execute the commands

```
chmod o+r /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target
chmod o+x /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/target
chmod o+x /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
chmod o+x /dir1/dir2/dir3
chmod o+x /dir1/dir2
chmod o+x /dir1
```

The `dir` variables value is altered in each iteration of the loop by removing the last `/` and everything after it.

Comment: thank you. This is what I had thought too. I wanted a confirmation that there are no options that we can use that would tell `chmod` to do this with a single command

Comment: @Sreeraj No, unfortunately not for a specific path of only directories like this. With `chmod -R` you could do it, but you would then change the permissions on a lot more than just those directories.

Comment: @kusalanda, Yes. Just found that this was feature-requested by someone and was rejected https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8736

Comment: @Sreeraj Huh, why would you need an option to `chmod` when a perfectly simple loop can do the same thing?